# Set autoincrement initial value in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to set the autoincrement initial value of the primary key on a table in Laravel 4 using Migrations with the Schema Builder?

I want to set the id of a table to start at 100. I know that is possible using pure SQL with `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 111111;`, but I want to maintain database versioning with Laravel Migrations.

Any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm afraid Laravel still doesn't have a way to change autoincrement values, but you can create a migration and do in it:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MyTableMigration extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function up()
    {
        $statement = "
                        ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 111111;
                    ";

        DB::unprepared($statement);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, it works fine on the migration. I still would like it to be on the framework itself. I've created an issue request on the repo, maybe they would implement it https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2713

Comment: @arielcr You can use:

`DB::update("ALTER TABLE {your table name} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");`

within the Framework and within migrations.

Comment: @casafred - brilliant suggestion - worked like a charm.

Comment: It was claimed this feature would not be widely used. But apparently it was being requested enough for them to decide they should lock the conversation: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2713#event-178381333

Locking discussions from further comment should not be a part of any open source project. It infuriates me.

Answer (score 1):

**Postgres**:

```
class MyTableMigration extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function up()
    {
        $statement = "ALTER SEQUENCE my_table RESTART WITH 111111";
        DB::unprepared($statement);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This ones throws the next error: ``Wrong object type: 7 ERROR:  "users" is not a sequence (SQL: ALTER SEQUENCE users RESTART WITH 7000)``