# How to set AUTO_INCREMENT in Laravel with Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on an application and my employer wants that the id in the user table should begin from 100,000 instead of 1. How can accomplish that? Is it a parameter in the Schema Builder itself? Or would I have to set something in the MySQL instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use SQL its self to do this. `ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;`.

**Or**

Do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938846/set-autoincrement-initial-value-in-laravel-4)

And use a unprepared statement;

```
$statement = "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;";

DB::unprepared($statement);
```

or

```
DB::update("ALTER TABLE {your table name} AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;");
```

Which could then be put within the migration that creates the table.

Comment: I guess I can do that but if there was something in Laravel itself, it would save me some time each time I am migrating the database?

Comment: You can use the DB::raw statement etc, but that still the same as if you were doing it ill edit to show you.

Comment: Can I use the DB:raw in the schema builder in the up() method after defining the schema? I think that would be possible, isn't it?

Comment: And to answer your question you can use anything within the method, aslong as there are no errors :)

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8 you can use from() or startingValue() in schema while creating the table to set the autoincrement

`$table->id()->from(100000);`

or use

`$table->id()->startingValue(100000);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am coming to you very late in the game, but if you use the truncate method, I believe the auto increment value of the primary key is automatically reset to 1.

i am currently working on a project where I am updating my developmet database with actual live data from the site I am updating.  I am re-assigning primary key values as data comes in so depending upon changes made to the live data, the primary key may change, so I often have to truncate and reset the auto increment value.  I have found in laravel 8 that issuing the truncate() method on a model achieves this.

e.g.

```
App\Models\User::truncate();
```

truncates the users table and resets the primary key 'id' auto increment value to 1;

Your having posted this many moons ago, yu probably have already discovered this I imagine.